# How to change the color of the "name"-variable behind #region

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I searched all around, but I can't find the option to change the color of "name" after #region in VS2012.

For example if I have the following code:

```
#region Test some code

CallSomeCode();

#endregion
```

How do I change the color of `Test some code`?

Comment: When the region is collapsed or when it is expanded?

Comment: When it is expanded, the color of "name" `Test some code` is normally black. I would like to change it to another color.

Comment: AFAIK there is no separate setting for font color of the region comment. It changes when you change font color for `Plain Text`.

Comment: Ok..., so I have to live with it. Thank you, for your quick response!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After looking at this and other posts on the Internet, this is what worked in VS 2015 for me:

#region and #endregion keywords: **Preprocessor Keyword** [immediately applied]

Text after the #region keyword: **Preprocessor Text** [immediately applied]

Collapsed region: **Collapsed Text (Collapsed)** [must restart Visual Studio]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In VS 2012 the following worked for me:

- To change color of #region / #endregion - set 'Preprocessor Keyword'
- To change the text after #region when collapsed- set 'Collapsed Text (Collapsed)'
- To change the text when expanded - set 'Plain Text', but beware this also changes ; ( [ etc

You may need to restart VS to take effect

*Personally I wish there was two types of comments - one for disabling code, and one for explanatory remarks.  They are two very different things but generally treated the same in most languages*

Answer (score 3):

In `Tools` menu Select `Option` Then `Environment` And `Fonts and Colors`

In display items list select `Collapsible tex`t and change it's color.

**Edited**

you can change color of `#region` from `Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors change the Preprocessor Keyword` but you cannot change color of text in front of `#region`

Comment: I didn't mean the collapsed view. As above said, I meant, when it's expanded. Another guy answered my question in the comment section of my question.